# Not getting the correct results when computing the Program

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm working on a class assignment where the user chooses radio button for each meal. I'm currently having trouble when the user puts in a loyalty number.  The book says if the user inputs a loyalty number that it deducts 5% of the total order cost for every 10 points a customer has earned. Customers cannot receive money back if their loyalty points exceed the full cost of their order.

```
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, 
               e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click

    Dim decCostofMeal As Decimal
    Dim decEstimateCost As Decimal
    Dim decLoyal As Decimal
    Dim decRoastedGarlic As Decimal = 3.99D
    Dim decFalafel As Decimal = 5.99D
    Dim decBabaganush As Decimal = 7.99D
    Dim decChicken As Decimal = 9.99D
    Dim decMushroom As Decimal = 6.99D

    ' If user enter loyalty points '

    If radRoastedGarlic.Checked Then
        decCostofMeal = decRoastedGarlic
    ElseIf RadFalafel.Checked Then
        decCostofMeal = decFalafel
    ElseIf RadBabaganush.Checked Then
        decCostofMeal = decBabaganush
    ElseIf RadChicken.Checked Then
        decCostofMeal = decChicken
    ElseIf RadMushroom.Checked Then
        decCostofMeal = decMushroom
    End If

    decEstimateCost = decCostofMeal

    If IsNumeric(txtPoints.Text) Then

        decLoyal = Convert.ToInt32(txtPoints.Text)

        If decLoyal > 0 Then
            decEstimateCost = decEstimateCost - (decEstimateCost * 0.05)
        End If
    End If

    lblResults.Text = decEstimateCost.ToString("C")
    lblResults.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Update
I tried to implement a case statement but is not working for some reason

```
If IsNumeric(txtPoints.Text) Then


        decLoyal = Convert.ToInt32(txtPoints.Text)

        Select Case decLoyal

            Case 10 - 19
                decEstimateCost = decEstimateCost - (decEstimateCost * 0.05)

            Case 20 - 29
                decEstimateCost = decEstimateCost - (decEstimateCost * 0.1)

            Case 30 - 39
                decEstimateCost = decEstimateCost - (decEstimateCost * 0.15)

            Case 40 - 49
                decEstimateCost = decEstimateCost - (decEstimateCost * 0.2)

            Case 50 - 59
                decEstimateCost = decEstimateCost - (decEstimateCost * 0.25)
            Case 60 - 69
                decEstimateCost = decEstimateCost - (decEstimateCost * 0.3)

            Case 70 - 79

                decEstimateCost = decEstimateCost - (decEstimateCost * 0.35)

            Case 80 - 89
                decEstimateCost = decEstimateCost - (decEstimateCost * 0.4)


        End Select
```

Comment: And your problem is? We are not a code writing service; please make an honest go at trying to solve the problem and then you may get help here - just leaving a blank and hoping we will fill it will likely get your question deleted. Please [read the advice here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: You forgot to describe *how* it is "not getting the correct results" ie how they are incorrect

Comment: I tried to implement a case statement but not working

Comment: a) you missed the conversion for *10 L points = 5%* b) If L points are whole numbers (cant have 6.5 points) is does not need to be an Decimal c) you can replace `IsNumeric` and `Convert.ToInt32` with `Integer.TryParse` which will not crash if they enter "I Like Pie" d) you also missed the test for `decEstimateCost  < 0` for too many points.  **not working** is the least helpful thing you could mutter.

Comment: Your case is absolutely wrong. `case 10 - 19` is interpreted as a subtraction, which means your statement is `case -9`.

Comment: you just need a single line of code to convert points to a `DiscountRate`. *5% per 10 points*

Comment: I've been trying to figure it out . This is my first time working with visual basic . Can please help me with either an example code or what I need to do to get it to work trying to figure it out

Comment: How can I implement it with a single line of code to convert

Comment: Following up on Ken's comment: Your cases should be `Case 10 To 19`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To improve your case execution you need to write

```
Case 10 To 19
```